# Dimension of a space S, proof that two M and N maximal sets must be equal.

Tags: linear-algebra

In the following blockquote is the proof for the followin statement: if $V_1,...,V_N$ and $W_1,...,W_M$ two maximal sets of M and N linearly independent vectors M=N. Here's the proof from *Physical Mathematics by Kevin Cahill*:

> Suppose $M < N$. Since the Us are complete, they span S, and so we may
>   express each of the N vectors Vi in terms of the M vectors Wj
>
> $$V_i=\sum_{j=1}^MA_{ij}W_j.$$
>
> Let $A_j$ be the vector with components $A_{ij}$. There are M < N such vectors,
>   and each has N > M components. So it is always possible to find a
>   nonzero N-dimensional vector $C$ with components $c_i$ that is orthogonal to all
>   $M$ vectors $A_j$.
>
> $$\sum_{i=1}^Nc_iA_{ij}=0$$
>   Thus the linear combination
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^Nc_iV_i=\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^Mc_iA_{ij}W_j=0.$$
>
> vanishes, **which implies that the $N$ vectors $V_i$ are linearly dependent. Since these
>   vectors are by assumption linearly independent, it follows that $N ≤ M$.**
>   Similarly, one may show that $M ≤ N$. Thus $M = N$.
>   The number of vectors in a maximal set of linearly independent vectors in a
>   vector space $S$ is the dimension of the vector space. Any N linearly independent
>   vectors in an N-dimensional space form a basis for it.

Why the linear dependence of the $V_i$s implies that $N≤M$, wouldn't the asumption that $M<N$ make $N<M$ wrong by reduction to absurdity making the only possible case possible for the above imhplication the equal sign i.e M=N?

Comment: It is a proof by contradiction. If $N>M$ then it leads to a contradiction, hence $N>M$ cannot be true and so $N \le M$. (I think proof by contradiction is inherently unsatisfying, but it often the most expedient.)